# How to reset bios/rom to factory setting if computer do not even run

Tags: motherboard, bios, rom

This is the continuation of [How do I reset BIOS to user factory setting](https://superuser.com/questions/462406/how-do-i-reset-bios-to-user-factory-setting)

Things are working.

I am finally able to login to windows.

With a big cactch.

I was concern I didn't flash my rom correctly. So I did it again, this time with more comprehensive reprogram all blocks option.

Result?

This time computer won't even run.

Nothing show up on screen.

I can't even get into bios. Nothing show up.

I truly have messed up.

Is there a jumper or something that get BIOS back to original factory setting?

Model is ECS H61H2-M2 1.0 bios

The manual is here: http://download.ecsusa.com/dlfileecs/manual/mb/H61H2-M2/H61H2-M2_V10_manual.pdf I still couldn't find the jumper to do.

There is a jumper in manual called clr_cmos. However, when I look the actual board the label is USB_PWR. I look around and cannot find anything labeled CLR_CMOS. Which one is pin 1, 2, and 3 is also unclear.
Some says about removing battery and wait for a while. Some says it only update the CMOS.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already tried removing CMOS battery?

Comment: mobo manufacturer and model would help...

Comment: The motherboard manual will tell you how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some motherboards get back to default BIOS settings just by removing and replacing the CMOS battery. But in most of the motherboards, you need to reset it using jumper pins (those 3 pins are labelled in most of the MBs).

For resetting, there are 3 pins provided on the motherboard with 2 pins always coupled (or shorted) using a small cap. Say the cap is shorting pins 2 and 3. You have to now remove the cap and put it on to short pins 1 and 2 for about 10-15 seconds. Then revert back the cap to pins 2 and 3.

Make sure the CMOS battery is not removed during this process.

Power on the system, BIOS should now be resetted back to its default settings.

Comment: That's what I am trying.

Answer (score 4):

Start studying the recovery techniques for bricked motherboards. There are some tricks very specific for particular vendors and models of motherboards.

For example (not exactly for your motherboard) you may need to insert PS2 keyboard, power board up keeping the F5-Alt and Shift simultaneously. Hold it for 10 seconds! then wait for particular leds to indicate that they read the USB drive with exactly FAT32, no more than 1GB partition, folder named exactly as described somewhere with firmware file named somehow. Then after nothing on the screen, wait for 5 minutes with power on, then hear 7 loud beeps, reboot. Etc.

Try to find the recovery repair document for your motherboard. Normally, contemporary flashes should have one overprotected area for this functions to keep products unbrickable. But the docs are hard to find.

It is possible. And so difficult just because you destroyed the firmware - whole bios (except the undestructible firmware loader itself), not just lost some "settings".

Comment: I rescued a non-booting Intel ATX mobo once - I had to write the firmware to a 3.5" floppy, set a jumper on the motherboard and power on. Nothing came up on the screen, but the floppy drive activity light came on for a bit, then it shutdown. When I reset the jumper and powered on, it came up normally. Happy days :)

Answer (score 0):

l think removing the CMOS battery helps. I just removed the battery for 10 minutes and when l powered on everything was normal.