# Laptop fails to boot after bios update

Tags: laptop, bios, hibernate

I have a Sony vaio s-series laptop.

Yesterday its auto update software prompted me to download and apply a bios update. I did so, but elected not to restart straight away as I was busy doing stuff.

Then, in the evening, having forgotten that I had this pending update, I closed the lid of the laptop which makes it hibernate.

This morning, it won't boot at all. No lights, no response, nothing. Have tried plugged in and not plugged in.

What are my options here?

Comment: Possibly see http://superuser.com/questions/462641/how-to-reset-bios-rom-to-factory-setting-if-computer-do-not-even-run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the battery for 5 minutes, replaced it and then on power-on, I saw a message that the bios update was completing. The computer then shut down, after which I was able to power up and function as normal.

Thanks for the cross-link in the comment to another thread that had this suggestion.